# Get intent filter for receivers

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get a list of receivers that handle `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` for other applications.

I can get only the apps with that action with this:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
final List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo ri : activities) {
    Log.i(TAG, "app name: " + ri.loadLabel(pm));
}
```

I can get a list of receivers with this code:

```
final List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_RECEIVERS);
for (final PackageInfo p : packs) {
    ActivityInfo[] receivers = p.receivers;
    if (receivers != null) {
        for (ActivityInfo ai : receivers) {
            Log.i(TAG, "receiver: " + ai.name);
        }
    }                   
}
```

After I get the receivers I cannot tell what the intent-filter/action is. If an app has two receivers I need to know which one handles `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`. Is there a way I can get this info?

Comment: Ok, think I figured it out. 

    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new                 Intent("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
    final List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo ri : activities) {
        Log.i(TAG, "app name: " + ri.loadLabel(pm));
        // What I needed:
        ActivityInfo ai = ri.activityInfo;
        if (ai != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "receiver:" + ai.name);
        }
    }

easy enough.

Comment: Hi Jared, you should post the answer to this question yourself, then you can make the code nicely formatted.  Don't worry, it's okay to accept your answer to your own question!

Comment: Thanks Dan. I went to do that but it wouldn't let me since I am a new member and have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question. I will when the 8 hours are up :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I reformatted for people. Use this and thanks for question.

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<String> startupApps = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : activities) {
    ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
    if (activityInfo != null) {
        startupApps.add(activityInfo.name);
    }
}
```