# Is there any way to query an specific type of Intent Filter capable apps?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm looking for a way to search in the device all the apps which are capable to filter Intents with action "VIEW" and category "BROWSABLE"?

I found the following links and learned how to list all Intent Filters, but how can I list only those having only the aforementioned parameters?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

[Get intent filter for receivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142386/get-intent-filter-for-receivers)

[How to filter specific apps for ACTION_SEND intent (and set a different text for each app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code should do more or less what you want. The main problem is that I don't think you will find any activity that filters for `CATEGORY_BROWSABLE` without also requiring **data** of a specific type. I tried it on my phone and I didn't get anything useful until I added the `setData()` call on the Intent.

```
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    // NOTE: Provide some data to help the Intent resolver
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    // Query for all activities that match my filter and request that the filter used
    //  to match is returned in the ResolveInfo
    List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities (intent,
                                   PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
    for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
        ActivityInfo activityInfo = info.activityInfo;
        IntentFilter filter = info.filter;
        if (filter != null && filter.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) &&
                  filter.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)) {
            // This activity resolves my Intent with the filter I'm looking for
            String activityPackageName = activityInfo.packageName;
            String activityName = activityInfo.name;
            System.out.println("Activity "+activityPackageName + "/" + activityName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David. Brilliant snippet! You mean query for specific MIME types with setData to find out specific results? So far I know if I provide an specific URI via setData() the MIME type is resolved by the Intent itself (I went for that approach to avoid the use of fileChooser() on other app). Maybe, it will be an ugly piece of code, but maybe I can provide to setData() a proper dummy URL as a constant to help filter accuracy. Some kind of an ugly comparator. I will give it a try based on your snippet and I let you know how it goes later. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks David, worked like a charm with minor adjustements (I just only need to get a boolean if the user has in device some kind of app). Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: The ```info.filter``` thing doesn't work. There's no field called filter in a ActivityInfo object.

Comment: @miguel `info.filter` refers to a `ResolveInfo` object, not an `ActivityInfo` object.