# Android: Filtering invite apps using Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on android Intent class to implement the 'Invite Friends' screen.
I used the below code for it.

The above code returns me the apps like bluetooth, flipboard, facebook, whatsapp etc.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.invite_friends));
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,getString(R.string.invite_send_tittle));

if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
{
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

What I need is only messaging(sms, whatsapp, twitter etc.) and email apps. 
How to get only messaging and email apps?

In short I am looking for invite options like WhatsApp.

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18585798/793943 check this ans

Comment: @sush: Thank you for responding. But I need all the invite apps that whatsapp gives when we click on its invite friends link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not do that since who knows how the user can communicate with friends - Twitter, Instagram, etc. As well there are millions of messengers and there is no way in `Intent` say `I need a messenger`.

If you still want to do selector for specific apps then you need own app selector with next steps:

1. Query all possible apps that are able to share text ([Is there any way to query an specific type of Intent Filter capable apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752081/is-there-any-way-to-query-an-specific-type-of-intent-filter-capable-apps))
2. Create own bottom sheet, dialogue or new screen with list

Comment: Thank you for answering. In my phone, when I use the Intent code(mentioned above), I get flipboard, bluetooth also in the invite apps list but this is not the case when I click on invite button of whatsapp. I too want to filter only such apps.

Comment: It was an example how to find apps that have intent filters. In particularly it looks for the apps that can show some information from a webpage. Sure thing WhatsApp developers did their job correctly and  show only apps that they want to show