# Not Receiving SMS using SmsManager in Android

Tags: android

I have a broadcast receiver class for receiving sms based on [this code](https://web.archive.org/web/20130327004652/http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87):

```
package package name;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Telephony;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    
    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
     
    public static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)){ 
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null){
                 
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                 
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                     
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                     
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
 
                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                     
 
                   // Show Alert
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
                                 "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();
                     
                } // end for loop
              } // bundle is null
 
       
    }    
        }
}
```

and this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="data.mobile.balance"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.03" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="PACKAGE NAME.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
       <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms"> 
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="PACKAGE NAME.android.action.broadcast"/> 
             <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I spent entire day running this code but still no success. What is wrong with my code ?

Do I have to register the broadcast receiver in my main activity ?

Comment: Have you tried a log print at the beginning of `onReceive()`? Is the Receiver in the same directory as `MainActivity`? What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: Hi Mike. My receiver is in the same directory as MainActivity. I tried to log print but it is showing nothing. I am testing on Android 4.3

Comment: Do you have any other SMS apps installed that might be intercepting the broadcast? E.g., Hangouts, GoSMS, etc.?

Comment: I had one earlier, but after reading other queries on stackoverflow I deleted it.

Comment: How are you testing, exactly? On an emulator? Device(s)?

Comment: I am testing it on my device.

Comment: Well, your code seemed correct, so I copied/pasted it, and it works for me. I would guess that you still have an app that is aborting the broadcast before yours gets it. You might check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10023734) to see how to get a list of all BroadcastReceivers for a certain action. Just substitute `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"` for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` action shown there.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED Tested on 5.0.1**

I made a simple demo & it's work like charm.

```
Manifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver
        android:name=".SmsReciever"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

Receiver:

public class SmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
public SmsReciever() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"sms Received",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String messageReceived = "";
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
        {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            messageReceived += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            messageReceived += "\n";
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, messageReceived, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Get the Sender Phone Number
        String senderPhoneNumber=msgs[0].getOriginatingAddress ();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with your problem but have you tried removing / reducing the 'priority' value of the receiver? According to google documentation it must be an integer greater than -1000 and less than 1000...